# Dojo require, connect to error when module failed loading

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dojo, requirejs

When I try to load nonexistent module, it fail with 404 error (of course). I want to handle this error but don't know how to connect to "error" event.

According to Dojo doc, I should be able to do that using [its micro event api](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#the-micro-event-api).

This code does not work.

```
var handle = require.on('error', function( error )
                 {
                     alert('Finally error')
                 });

require(['nonexistent/module'], function ( m )
{
     alert('Module was loaded correctly')           
});
```

Dojo version is 1.7.1, browser latest Chrome.

Comment: A `require.on` handler like this is called for every error event after that point in time, right?  I have used `var h = require.on('error', function (err) { h.remove(); ...etc }` but this will only handle the first error event, and not necessarily the one caused by the `nonexistent/module`.  Any more graceful way to only handle the error for your module, short of searching the error string for your module name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on this one *is* a bit curious. I *can* get the 'error' event to fire after a short timeout (dojoConfig.waitSeconds) after a failed xhr require, but only in async mode, and only with a dev build of Dojo.

Why?  Well, only async mode raises the event, and it looks like the CDN build was built with dojo-timeout-api == 0.

Can you use your own custom (SDK) version of Dojo?

@mschr - your jsfiddle sample works if you use Dojo (nightly) instead of Dojo 1.7.2 - same reason as above.

Comment: I'm using sdk version of dojo in async mode. Setting dojoConfig.waitSeconds to some value finally raises error. Setting it to 0 does not. Works also with 1.7.1. Thank you.

Comment: awesome, had no idea google would leave out the goodies :) this post actually led me to getting a long sought feature implemented! monitoring loader has stressed me, when trying to post progress of loading modules in. This event api did the trick

Answer (score 1):

try it with debugging set

```
<script src="{{baseUrl}}/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, debug: true, debugAtAllCost:true"></script>
```

Edit; no such luck - it seems that docs are ahead of implementation here..

created a fiddle for the purpose of maybe finding a solution, concept is nice, would enjoy to use this myself

http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/h6bXQ/