# What is a cleaner way to dynamically load google.maps using AMD?

Tags: google-maps, dojo, js-amd

I'm wanting to take advantage of the google maps loader callback as demonstrated here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async

I have a working example of doing this using AMD and promises.  To load and consume the API:

```
require(["path/to/google-maps-api-v3"], function (api) {
  api.then(function (googleMaps) {
    // consume the api
   });
});
```

Here's my module def which I'd prefer return google.maps after it's full loaded instead of a deferred:

```
define(["dojo/Deferred"], function (Deferred) {
        var d = new Deferred();
        dojoConfig["googleMapsReady"] = function () {
            delete dojoConfig["googleMapsReady"];
            d.resolve(google.maps);
        }
        require(["http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=dojoConfig.ipsx.config.googleMapsReady&"]);
        return d;
    });
```

But solution returns a promise instead of the fully initialized google.maps.  I'd prefer it to appear like a regular AMD module but can't see how.

Comment: Solutions seems to be to create a plugin:
e.g. https://gist.github.com/JanMisker/3884283

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking "AMD Plugin" as the answer before I got down to reading your comment.  Writing an AMD plugin allows you to control when the module resolves, while still being able to load it as straightforwardly as any other AMD module dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an AMD plugin.  Here's the one I created based on JanMisker's example:

```
define(function () {
    var cb ="_asyncApiLoaderCallback";
    return {
        load: function (param, req, loadCallback) {
            if (!cb) return;
            dojoConfig[cb] = function () {
                delete dojoConfig[cb];
                cb = null;
                loadCallback(google.maps);
            }
            require([param + "&callback=dojoConfig." + cb]);
        }
    };
});
```

Usage example:

```
require(["plugins/async!//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"]);
```

Comment: Yes, with a minor tweak. `loadCallback(google.maps);`

Comment: I've been using this approach, now we find ourselves with users in China for whom Google is blocked.  I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449207/dojo-require-connect-to-error-when-module-failed-loading helpful, set a handler for the require error event and call `loadCallback(false)` yourself, then the code that called require can handle the failure gracefully.